# VF Controller Test Class

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, controller

I have been trying to create a test class for my controller for my visual force page and I am not grasping the concepts behind it, can someone help me get started? I have tried a few things but I have never done a test class like this.

```
Public with sharing class SuperSearchController {
Public List<Opportunity> optyList {get;set;}
Public List<Lead> leadList{ get;set; }
Public List<Split__c> splitList{get;set;}
Public List<Quote> qList{get;set;}
Public List<Sampling__c> sampList{get;set;}
public List<Contact> contacts {get;set;}

Public SuperSearchController(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
}

public Map <Id, Account> getAccountAlias(String alias){
    Set<id> aliasId = new Set<id>();

    for(Alias__c a : [SELECT Name,Super_Customer__c FROM Alias__c WHERE Super_Customer__c =: alias]){
        aliasId.add(a.Super_Customer__c);
    }

    List<Account> accountKeys = [SELECT Name, Super_Customer__c FROM Account WHERE Super_Customer__c IN :aliasId];

    Map<id, Account> aMap  = new Map<id,Account>();

      for(Account account: accountKeys){
        aMap.put(account.ID, account);
    }
    system.debug('This is aMap ' +aMap);
    return aMap;
}

public List<Split__c> getSplits(Set<Id> accountIds) {
    return [
        SELECT Name,id,CreatedById,End_Customer_Account__c  
        FROM Split__c
        WHERE End_Customer_Account__c IN:accountids            
    ];
    //
     //  or Production_site in account
}

public List<Opportunity> getOpps(Set<Id> accountIds){
    return [
    Select Name,StageName 
    From Opportunity 
    WHERE AccountID IN : accountIds

    ];
    //  
}
/*     public List<Opportunity> getSamp(Set<Id> accountIds){
    return [
    Select Name,ID 
    From Sampling__c 
    WHERE AccountID IN : accountIds

    ];
    //  
}*/


Public PageReference runSearch() {
    String superCustomer = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('superCustomer');


        Map<Id, Account> accountMap = getAccountAlias(superCustomer);

  if (!accountMap.isEmpty()) {
        this.splitList = this.getSplits(accountMap.keySet());
        this.optyList = this.getOpps(accountMap.keySet());
    //    this.sampList = this.getSamp(accountMap.keySet());
        // Repeat for other types
    }    
    return null;
}
}
```

After using Keith's link I came up with this, which still doesn't make any sense to me..

```
public static testMethod void testMyController() {
    PageReference pageRef = Page.SuperCustomerSearch;
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

    SuperSearchController controller = new SuperSearchController();
    String nextPage = controller.runSearch().getUrl();

    // Verify that page fails without parameters
    System.assertEquals('/apex/failure?error=noParam', nextPage);

    // Add parameters to page URL
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('qp', 'yyyy');

    // Instantiate a new controller with all parameters in the page
    controller = new SuperSearchController(); 
    controller.getAccountAlias();
    controller.getOpps();
    controller.getSplits();
    nextPage = controller.save().getUrl();

    // Verify that the success page displays
    System.assertEquals('/apex/SuperCustomerSearc', nextPage);
    Lead[] leads = [SELECT AccountId, FQ_Design_In__c FROM Opportunity WHERE RSM__c != null ];
    System.assertEquals('firstlast@acme.com', leads[0].email);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not quite sure what do you mean by doesn't make sense. But it seems to me that your test code wouldn't compile. In your controller/extension code, the constructor is:

```
Public SuperSearchController(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)
```

While in your test code, you tried to initialize it by:

```
SuperSearchController controller = new SuperSearchController();
```

which will probably not work.

It seems to me that your controller is actually an extension of StandardSetController. To initialize that, you need code like this:

```
List<account> accountList = [SELECT Name FROM Account LIMIT 20];
ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(accountList);
SuperSearchController controller = new SuperSearchController(ssc);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I mean it doesn't make sense because I don't understand the logic behind it, I have never written a test class for a controller and trying to copy someone elses isn't going to work

Comment: So, does the code above works for you?

Comment: It does work, thank you.  The next step it to actually get my logic to execute such as getAccountAlias() and my other gets, it gets in there but it never adds anything because their is nothing to add

Comment: I think I am getting tripped up because I am treating it as a Trigger test class

Answer (score 0):

Your Apex test has to setup the SObjects that your controller works with, instantiate the controller and then set its properties and invoke its methods and assert the outcomes. Like any other unit test, you need to examine the logic in the controller and make sure that the tests both cover that code and ensure that the outcomes are as expected.

The corresponding Visualforce page is not really involved in the Apex testing process: it is only the Apex controller logic that is being tested.

This [Testing Custom Controllers and Controller Extensions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_error_handling.htm) provides a simple example.